# Change ImageSource during Storyboard in code behind

Tags: c#, wpf, image, xaml, storyboard

I need to create a storyboard where I change the ImageSource of my Image-control to make it smoother but I don't have any clue how to do this since I'm new to storyboards.

Can someone explain me how to do this pls?

Here is my XAML : 
(CenterScaleImage is just an Image-ctrl with 2 extra properties)

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" DataContext="{Binding Main, Mode=OneWay, Source={StaticResource Locator}}" Background="White">
        <Controls:CenterScaleImage x:Name="Image" Margin="0" Source="{Binding PropVisibleImage}" ScaleFactor="{Binding PropScaleFactor}" CenterScaleX="{Binding PropScaleCenterX}" CenterScaleY="{Binding PropScaleCenterY}">
            <Controls:CenterScaleImage.RenderTransform>
                <TransformGroup>
                    <ScaleTransform ScaleY="{Binding PropScaleFactor}" ScaleX="{Binding PropScaleFactor}" CenterX="{Binding PropScaleCenterX}" CenterY="{Binding PropScaleCenterY}"/>
                    <SkewTransform/>
                    <RotateTransform/>
                    <TranslateTransform X="{Binding PropPanHorizontal}" Y="{Binding PropPanVertical}"/>
                </TransformGroup>
            </Controls:CenterScaleImage.RenderTransform>
        </Controls:CenterScaleImage>
    </Grid>
```

Comment: Read [this guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752312.aspx) from MSDN

Comment: @milter thx but I need to do it in code-behind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot change the Image Source as part of a storyboard. Storyboard animations require the interpolation values to be calculable between one state and the next state in an animated transition (tweening) - swapping images makes no sense in this scenario. ~The best thing to do is to create a data or property trigger to swap the image source if that s what you require.